# Eclipse + Python: Stack overflow during debug - not run

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, stack-overflow

I have the following *Python* code in *Eclipse* which causes *stack overflow* when debugging:

```
v = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
```

The method calls are part of the [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/) library and the Error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Default\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_920333535\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 963, in trace_dispatch
     return additionalInfo.CreateDbFrame((self, filename, additionalInfo, t, frame)).trace_dispatch(frame, event, arg)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded Fatal Python error:
Cannot recover from stack overflow.

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
information.
```

The part of the code that causes the error is:

```
v = ogr.Feature(...)
```

but it only happens if I debug (F11) but not when I'm running (CTRL+F11).

**What might be happening and what can I do to prevent this *stack overflow*?**